# What is the dagum type 2 probability distribution function?

Tags: distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

I have been searching for dagum type 2 probability distribution function for several hours but all I have found is the cumulative density function of the mentioned distribution which is as follows:

$$F(x) = \delta + (1-\delta)\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^{-a}\right)^{-p}$$

Reference : [A Guide to the Dagum Distributions, page 4](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/123385/1/wp2007-23.pdf)

Are there any PDF for dagum type 2 and 3 distribution just like type 1?

Comment: Take the derivative.  Equivalently, change the variables for the PDF of $\log(x)$ given under "Basic Properties."

Comment: @whuber so the PDF would be: $$f(x) = \frac{ap(1+\delta)}{b^{-a}}x^{-(a+1)}\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^{-a}\right)^{-(p+1)}$$

Comment: Close.  See equation (4) for confirmation of the derivative, but then read the rest of the page to learn why when $\delta \gt 0,$ this distribution *does not have a density at $x=0.$*

Comment: You might find https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214485, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335547, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306491 helpful.

Comment: @whuber but equation (4) is for type 1 dagum distribution

Comment: That contradicts what you write in your question.  And I was referring to (4) only to check your differentiation: the text *after* that equation discusses the type II distribution.  Start reading in the middle of the page.