# Predictive Distribution in Gaussian Process Derivation

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

In Gaussian Process for Machine Learning [(Rasmussen and Williams)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf), pg 11, we are given the following predictive distribution:

$$p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, X, \mathbf{y}\right)=\int p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w}$$

We are also given the definition: $f_{*} \triangleq f\left(\mathbf{x}_{*}\right)$ where $f(\mathrm{x})=\mathrm{x}^{\top} \mathrm{w}$ and $y=f(\mathbf{x})+\varepsilon$.

I understand that one may compute the distribution shown above by doing the following:

$$E[f_{*}] = \mathrm{x}^{\top}E[\mathrm{w}]$$
$$V[f_{*}] = \mathrm{x}^{\top}V[\mathrm{w}]\mathrm{x}$$

We then plug in the expressions for the mean and variance of our posterior over w. Essentially, we are computing the mean and variance of a scaled Gaussian random variable as we already established that the posterior distribution over w is Gaussian.

However, I have a problem with the integral shown above. I understand how to arrive at this expression (sum rule, product rule, and conditional independence). However, the $p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right)$ term is bothering me.

I have seen derivations where this term is replaced with $p\left(y_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right)$. This makes more sense to me as, due to the Gaussian noise, this term would be a Gaussian distribution and the integral of the product of two Gaussian distributions is a Gaussian distribution (provided proper normalisation). However, wouldn't $p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right)$ be a delta function at $f_{*} = \mathrm{x}^{\top}_{*} \mathrm{w}$? Am I missing something here?

Any advice would be greatly welcomed! Cheers!

Comment: I think you should add the self study tag.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Just added it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a delta function. We're basically finding the pdf of $f(\mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{w})$ given the derived posterior pdf for $\mathbf{w}$. For example see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16509/pdf-for-a-function-of-random-variables). So
$$
p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right) = \delta(f_{*} - \mathbf{x}_*^T \mathbf{w})
$$
Our integral becomes
$$
\begin{align}
p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, X, \mathbf{y}\right) &= \int p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w} \\
&= \int \delta(f_{*} - \mathbf{x}_*^T \mathbf{w}) \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{w} \mid \mu, \Sigma) d \mathbf{w} \\
&= \ldots \\
&= \mathcal{N}(f_{*} \mid \mathbf{x}_{*}^T \mu, \mathbf{x}_{*}^T \Sigma \mathbf{x}_{*}) \\
\end{align}
$$
The integral is easy to take in the 1D case as a sanity check. The multivariate case is a bit more annoying but basically the delta function constrains one dimension of $\mathbf{w}$, and the rest is doable by completing the square to get something of the form

$$
p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, X, \mathbf{y}\right) = \mathcal{N}(f_{*}) \int d\mathbf{u} \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{u})
$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ is $n-1$ dimensional and the integral manifestly just goes to 1.

Comment: How to get the first equality ?