# Predictive Distribution in Gaussian Process for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I am reading [Gaussian Process for Machine Learning](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf) equation 2.9, where it is deriving the predictive distribution

$$p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y}) = \int p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w}.$$

I tried to do it analytically like in equation 2.8 but the terms are all over the place. I also tried to treat it as a delta function as in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410110/predictive-distribution-in-gaussian-process-derivation). But I still cannot understand it.

$$
\begin{align*}
p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y}) &= \int p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w} \\[5pt]
&= \int \delta(f_* - \mathbf{x}_*^T \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w}.
\end{align*}
$$

Properites of delta functions includes

$$
\begin{align*}
\int \delta(x - x_0) f(x) dx = f(x_0)
\end{align*}
$$

which I cannot see how to use it here. I also read the matrix variant of the delta function from the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) equation 548

$$
\int \delta(\mathbf{x} - A\mathbf{s}) p(\mathbf{s}) d\mathbf{s} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}} p(A^+\mathbf{x}),
$$

where $A^+$ is the psudo inverse of $A$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y}) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(\mathbf{x}_* \mathbf{x}_*^T)}} p_{\mathbf{w}}((\mathbf{x}_* \mathbf{x}_*^T)^{-1} \mathbf{x}_* f_* | X, \mathbf{y})
\end{align*}
$$

and I am stuck here. Sorry for creating one more post because I cannot make comments right now.

Comment: As I have done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582362), $p(f_*|\mathbf{x_*, w})=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{w^Tx^*},\sigma_f^2)$ does give the result (take the limit $\sigma_f\to 0$ - making it delta function). But this does not seem to be the most general method.

Comment: `most general` in the sense of directly using delta function properties as you've done

Answer (score 0):

Without having looked into the specific context of the application to Gaussian processes, I think you may be overcomplicating things - I read it as just the product rule of probabilities with conditioning, followed by marginalisation so:

$$\begin{align}p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y}) 
&= \int p(f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w} \\
&=  \int p(f_*, \mathbf{w} | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes. It is true. But we do not have the distribution of $f_*, \mathbf{w} | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y}$. We only $f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{w} \sim N(\mathbf{x}_*^T \mathbf{w}, \sigma_n^2)$, and $\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y} \sim N(\mathbf{\bar{w}}, A^{-1})$, where $\mathbf{\bar{w}}$ and $A$ are some functions of $X$ and $\mathbf{y}$. We are trying to show that $f_* | \mathbf{x}_*, X, \mathbf{y} \sim N(\mathbf{x}_*^T \mathbf{\bar{w}}, \mathbf{x}_*^T A^{-1} \mathbf{x}_*)$. But I am confused by the different dimensions of $f_*$ and $\mathbf{w}$.